Issue with Crypto Object in Angular
I am using Angular 17. I have deployed my Angular project on IIS. Everything was good till I used MSAL services (Microsoft login) in my project. Then I published it again, and then I faced this error. (The crypto object or function is not available.)


Any chance that your app is running in HTTP context? MSAL only supports HTTPS.

Here's the browser compatibility chart - note that "Secure context required" is true for all modern browsers.

Similar: Web Crypto API without ssl

Not a perfect duplicate, but close: Blazor WASM error: 'window.crypto.randomUUID is not a function'

ohh , i don't have the ssl certificate ..
must i have it to fix the problem ?

Yes, probably you will need a valid certificate

Please share more details, like the error message in text form (not hidden in a screenshot), the code involved, and your attempts to resolve the error
